# How to mount linux partition on android?

Tags: android, mount, partition

How to mount partition 2nd on android? Filesystem is ext2. Size is 8 gb, on this partition is installed Linux Ububuntu 13.04 PL. I have got error `Device busy`. What am I doing wrong?

Detail in console:

```
app_149@android:/ $ su
root@android:/ # mount
rootfs / rootfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock0 /system yaffs2 rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock2 /data yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock1 /cache yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock3 /system/vendor yaffs2 ro,relatime 0 0
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /data/sdext2 vfat rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0133,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:1 /mnt/sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:1 /mnt/secure/asec vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs ro,relatime,size=0k,mode=000 0 0
root@android:/ # fdisk /dev/bloc/mmcblk0

The number of cylinders for this disk is set to 3880.
There is nothing wrong with that, but this is larger than 1024,
and could in certain setups cause problems with:
1) software that runs at boot time (e.g., old versions of LILO)
2) booting and partitioning software from other OSs
   (e.g., DOS FDISK, OS/2 FDISK)

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/block/mmcblk0: 31.9 GB, 31914983424 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3880 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

              Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/block/mmcblk0p1               1        2315    18594213+  b Win95 FAT32
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2   *        2316        3359     8385930  83 Linux
/dev/block/mmcblk0p3            3360        3880     4184932+  e Win95 FAT16 (LBA)

Command (m for help):
root@android:/ # mkdir /mnt/linux
mkdir failed for /mnt/linux, File exists
255|root@android:/ # rmdir /mnt/linux
root@android:/ # mkdir /mnt/linux
root@android:/ # mount -t ext2 /dec/block/mmcblk0p2 /mnt/linux
mount: No such file or directory
255|root@android:/ # mount -t ext2 /dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /mnt/linux
mount: Device or resource busy
255|root@android:/ # mount -t linux /dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /mnt/linux
mount: No such device
255|root@android:/ #
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't mount something that is already mounted:

```
/dev/block/mmcblk0p2 /data/sdext2 vfat rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0133,dmask=0002,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0

/dev/block/mmcblk0p2 - already mounted in /data/sdext2
```

Comment: I want to mount blk0p3, not blk0p2 - is mounted by Link2SD, but blk0p3?